# A* algorithm for finding shortest path in a graph

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks, algorithm

[FindShortestPath](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindShortestPath.html) finds the shortest path between two vertices in an edge-weighted graph, allowing a choice between the [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_Ford) algorithms. In my (limited) understanding, both of these algorithms fall into the breadth-first category.

My question is if there are accessible implementations of depth-first shortest path algorithms like [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_algorithm) for edge-weighted graphs in Mathematica.

I am aware of the question [How to display each step of an A star algorithm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39465/how-to-display-each-step-of-an-a-star-algorithm), but before delving into modifying that code so as to work with weighted graphs I wanted to make sure that I don't re-invent the wheel.

In fact, I haven't been able to locate an efficient implementation (using fancy data structures etc.) of A* for edge-weighted graphs in *any* programming language, but that would probably be a question for another site.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy solution. Mathematica still seems to fall a bit short on Path Algorithms.

Comment: Could you please explain what this implementation would be able to do what `FindShortestPath` cannot already?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Szabolcs. I'm not a computer scientist, but when I wrote the question, my undertanding was that A star can have a better run time compexity on certain types of graphs than Dijstra or Bellman-Ford. I agree that it would likely not add functionality as such to `FindShortestPath`.