# How can we make an algorithm with the A* method in Mathematica with 5 different flight routes?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, programming, algorithm

I need to find the shortest path with the A* algorithm using Mathematica.
I have 5 different flight routes with coordinates. They start and end at the same point. Between every point there is a wind factor between 0.9 and 1.1 influencing the distance. Distance * wind factor = new distance.
The distance from a new point to the end point should be * 0.9 (heuristic)

Comment: The answer is probably "yes". Alone, a lot of context is missing which makes it har to show _how_ to do it.

Comment: There was a question about A star sometime ago. [how-to-display-each-step-of-an-a-star-algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39465/how-to-display-each-step-of-an-a-star-algorithm) with some implementation. Do not know if this is the same thing as you are asking about.

Comment: Also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43472/a-algorithm-for-finding-shortest-path-in-a-graph

Comment: Actually that was general case and its specific for 5 different flight routes. And different because here are flight routes. Answers for those 2 questions don't fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Code for a minimal working example seems needed here.